# Want to stay on same Page after button click event

Tags: sharepoint-2010, runtime-error

I am working with small application in SharePoint. I have a custom application page on which i am loading `.ascx` Control under `Page_Load()` method. `.ascx` Control is a small form with text boxes and a button. Now when i click on button, the information successfully saved in the list in SharePoint, but it gives Runtime error:

> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on the local server machine, please create a customErrors tag
>   within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory
>   of the current web application. This customErrors tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

I have checked my web.config, and customError tag is there and mode is set to "Off".

what is problem ? I want to stay on same page after clicking button.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely staying on the same page as asp.net page always posts back to itself only and redirects only if you explicitly ask it to do so. There is either some error in your code or in you web.config file.

Further the error is in the block of postback code
i.e. Somewhere on your page there is some code like

```
if (isPostBack)
{
  **//Some code with error**
}
```

as the error occurs only when you post back.

I would suggest you go step by step debugging and pin point the exact line of error.

Answer (score 0):

By using Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); solves the above issue.